# Swift reuse overloaded initializers of a UIHostingController?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uihostingcontroller

I have a UIHostingController with two very similar initializers, just with different parameters.  Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class ExampleViewController: UIHostingController<ExampleView> {
  public let var1: Int
  public let var2: String

  public init(var1: Int, var2: String) {
    self.var1 = var1
    self.var2 = var2
    super.init(rootView: ExampleView(var1, var2))

  }

  public convenience init(var1: Int) {
    self.var1 = var1
    self.var2 = “”
    super.init(rootView: ExampleView(var1, ""))
  }
}
```

Since my real use case is more complicated than this example, it would be great if I could reuse the shared logic in the initializers, something like this:

```
public class ExampleViewController: UIHostingController<ExampleView> {
  public let var1: Int
  public let var2: String

  public init(var1: Int, var2: String) {
    self.var1 = var1
    self.var2 = var2
    super.init(rootView: ExampleView(var1, var2))
  }

  public init(var1: Int) {
    self.init(var1: var1, var2: "")
  }
}
```

However, I am unable to reference `self`/`self.init` until all properties are set and `super.init` is called.  Does this mean that I’m not able to reuse the initializer logic, or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Call the super init first, *then* initialize your own properties

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct; deduplicating initialization logic is a good idea.

For it to work correctly, you need to mark you second initializer with `convenience`:

```
// ...
  public convenience init(var1: Int) {
    self.init(var1: var1, var2: “”)
  }
```

Usually these are the most clear when most initializers are just a customization/specialization implemented in terms of some other centralized initializer. A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: Swift designated initializer call hierarchy]

Ideally, you only have 1 designated initializer at each level, where possible.

---

However, in this case, you can just leverage Swift's ability to have default parameter values, and get away with just a single simple initializer:

```swift
public class ExampleViewController: UIHostingController<ExampleView> {
  public let var1: Int
  public let var2: String

  public init(var1: Int, var2: String = "") {
    super.init(rootView: ExampleView(var1, var2))
    self.var1 = var1
    self.var2 = var2
  }
}
```

This is likely just a toy example, but I'll caution anyway: `""` is *almost never* an appropriate default value for strings (contrary to the defaults baked into other languages, like 0 values in Go or default-initialized values in Java).

Comment: I'm seeing "property 'self.var1' not initialized at super.init call" when I move the super.init call before setting the property.

Comment: Upon further consideration, default parameters and one initializer is enough, I was overcomplicating the issue.  Thank you!

Comment: @user11799 Oh I got the ordering totally backwards in my head. This is what I get for not compiling before posting :p Just be careful with default parameters. A lot of defaults (_especially_ for strings) don't make sense.